# How to show only the first two digits with NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have a number for an example 1329094. I want to get only the first two digits that I make see 13

I create `NSNumberFormatter` like

```
 func setReceivedChart(description: [String], value: [Double]) {
        var descriptionString: String!
        var formatterNumber: NSNumber!
        var chartDataEntryArray = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for item in 0..<description.count {
            let chartEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: value[item], xIndex: item)
            chartDataEntryArray.append(chartEntry)
            descriptionString = description[item]
            formatterNumber = value[item]
        }
        let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: chartDataEntryArray, label: "")
        dataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = true // change
        dataSet.drawCubicEnabled = true
        dataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
        dataSet.circleRadius = 3.0 // for iphone
        dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true

        print(descriptionString)


        let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .NoStyle
       numberFormatter.usesSignificantDigits = true
       numberFormatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 2

        dataSet.valueFormatter = numberFormatter

        // set color 47 206 255
        dataSet.fillColor = UIColor(red: 47/255, green: 206/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
        let chartData = LineChartData(xVals: description, dataSet: dataSet)
        receivedChartView.data = chartData
    }
```

But I see the result 1300000

**UPDATE**
I cannot because the data is required for the graphics, I measure them in bytes for the construction of a good schedule. If I initially transformed into different values such as megabytes and bytes, the 704 bytes will be more than 1.5 megabytes in the chart

Comment: Please do **not** include code that is not relevant to the topic you are asking about. It just makes the relevant code less visibile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not convert the number to `String`, strip the unwanted digits and convert it back.

```
let number = 1329094
let numberAsString = String(number)
let subString = numberAsString.substringToIndex(numberAsString.startIndex.advancedBy(2))
let trimmedNumber = Int(subString)
```

or

```
let number = 1329094
let numberOfDigits = String(number).characters.count
let trimmedNumber = number / Int(pow(10.0, Double(numberOfDigits - 2)))
```

Comment: Because the data is required for the graphics, I measure them in bytes for the construction of a good schedule. If I initially transformed into different values such as megabytes and bytes, the 704 bytes will be more than 1.5 megabytes in the chart.

Comment: Then you probably need something like `NSByteCountFormatter`.

Comment: I cannot use NSByteCountFormatter. I also tried it. Because iOS Chart library support only NSNumberFormatter

Comment: I don't know that library and you didn't mention it in your question. Basically you cannot strip most significant digits from a number with NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: PS: `NSValueTransformer` might help you

Comment: I think add my method to library and fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a number formatter that will scale the number (remove trailing zeroes) except for `NSByteCountFormatter`.  Therefore you will need to scale each data point in the loop before adding it to your chart array. Maybe something like this.

**NOTE:
It seems very risky to chart something only using nonzero, significant figures.  Charting 12, 120, 1200, 12000, and 120000000000000 will all show the same values.**

```
func setReceivedChart(description: [String], value: [Double]) {
  let significantFigures = NSNumberFormatter()
  significantFigures.usesSignificantDigits = true
  significantFigures.maximumSignificantDigits = 2

  var chartDataEntryArray = [ChartDataEntry]()
  for item in 0..<description.count {
    if let datum = significantFigures.stringFromNumber(value[item]) {
      datum.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("0", withString: "", options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)
      let chartEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: Double(datum), xIndex: item)
      chartDataEntryArray.append(chartEntry)
    }
    else {
      // handle error, keep charDataEntryArray in sync with description[]
    }
  }

  let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: chartDataEntryArray, label: "")
  dataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
  dataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = true // change
  dataSet.drawCubicEnabled = true
  dataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
  dataSet.circleRadius = 3.0 // for iphone
  dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true

  let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
  numberFormatter.numberStyle = .NoStyle
  dataSet.valueFormatter = numberFormatter

  // set color 47 206 255
  dataSet.fillColor = UIColor(red: 47/255, green: 206/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
  let chartData = LineChartData(xVals: description, dataSet: dataSet)
  receivedChartView.data = chartData
}
```

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885486/how-to-replace-the-values-of-labels-in-ios-charts